# how to add values to dictionary with same keys in python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to convert a csv file into a dictionary , without using pandas: -

```
101,Minneapolis,shoes,2,Air
102,Chicago,shoes,1,Air
103,New York,shoes,5,Reebok
104,Punjab,slippers,1,adidas
105,Delhi,slippers,2,crocs
```

I want to store data in a dictionary-like : 
`{'shoes': 8,'slippers':3}`

I'm able to covert required columns into lists :

```
l1 = ['shoes', 'shoes', 'shoes', 'slippers', 'slippers']
l2 = ['2', '1', '5', '1', '2']
```

I'm using below line to code to convert these two lists in the dictionary :

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
    dict[l1[i]] = [l2[i]]
```

but it's giving me output as :

`{'shoes': ['5'], 'slippers': ['2']}`

not sure how to get the desired output where it shoes the type of order in key and total orders for that type in a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find anything more concise than the following [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, sep=',')
res= df.groupby(2)[3].sum().to_dict()
print(res)   # {'shoes': 8, 'slippers': 3}
```

---

Another way is using combination of `csv.reader` object and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('test.csv') as f:
    res = defaultdict(int)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        res[row[2]] += int(row[3])
print(dict(res))
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the same code in hackerrank but getting an error that 'pandas'  module not found. I'm wondering if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: are you able to install `pandas` with `pip install pandas` ?

Comment: I'm trying to solve one of the problems on hackrank(https://www.hackerrank.com/), I'm not sure if pip install pandas work there.

Comment: how can I store that dict(res) output in dictionary, I think 'dict' is not a callable object

Comment: @Indiejay88 what's the issue of saving that in variable `d = dict(res)` ?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-57c89e1db36a> in <module>()
      8     for row in csv.reader(f):
      9         res[row[2]] +=int(row[3])
---> 10 d = dict(res)
     11 print(d)
     12 

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @Indiejay88, you have troubles with your environment. I've posted a working solution. I would not rely on online editors, solve your local troubles

Comment: The above code doesn't work with pythonn 2.7 interpreter. It worked when I changed the interpreter to 3.7 in pycharm. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Indiejay88, please always specify Python version (as a tag) in your questions on SO (`python` category)